# How to access generated files in bazel-bin?

Tags: bazel

I'm using some macro which generates *.kt files in `bazel-bin` folder.

My plan was to encapsulate those kt files in a `kt_jvm_library`.

I am trying this but it's not working:

```
kt_jvm_library(
    name = "generated-stuff",
    srcs = ["bazel-bin/src/main/java/com/example/Hello.kt"],
    deps = [
        ...
    ],
)
```

In Gradle I could just do:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir ('${buildDir.absolutePath}/generated/...')
        }
        resources {
            srcDir ('config')
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to find an equivalent in Bazel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [label](https://bazel.build/concepts/labels) to refer to outputs from other rules, so that Bazel understands where they're coming from to set up the correct dependencies. Depending on your BUILD file layout, that would be something like `//src/main/java/com/example:Kello.kt` or `//src/main/java:com/example/Hello.kt`. If it's in the same BUILD file, then just `:Hello.kt` would work too. It depends on where the [package](https://bazel.build/concepts/build-ref#packages) boundary is (basically where the deepest-nested `BUILD` file is).

Also, depending on the rule, you may not be able to refer to `Hello.kt` directly, you may have to use the label of the rule instead. Using the label of a rule in `srcs` will typically use its [default outputs](https://bazel.build/extending/rules#default_outputs).

Comment: thanks Brian. this is the repo i am trying to make work: https://github.com/vgrec/bazel-graphql-poc

if you have some time, please try to build it. you will see that the output is generated in the bazel-bin folder by the Apollo GraphQL compiler. however i am not able to access that generated output.

the original repo owner also faced the same issue.

Comment: not sure if this is the culprit based on your link above? https://github.com/vgrec/bazel-graphql-poc/blob/251d3660d67e346f4eac73a6757e70fe1802714a/src/main/java/com/example/compiler/rules.bzl#L16

Comment: just struggling with understanding what is the target name for those generated files. thought it would be something like this but its not working.

"//src/main/java/com/example:apollo/com/example/LaunchListQuery.kt"

Comment: I don't see any `kt_jvm_library` rules, and I'm not familiar enough with the Java ecosystem to guess where they should go. If you have a minimized example, could you edit your question to include a link to it, with the parts you think are most relevant quoted, and the error you get when you try it? That will be more helpful to other people reading it, either because they have the same situation or those who may be able to answer.

Comment: this is the BUILD file of the compiler function which uses apollo to generate the kotlin model: https://github.com/vgrec/bazel-graphql-poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/compiler/BUILD

this is the Main class which tries to access generated kotlin files: https://github.com/vgrec/bazel-graphql-poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/Main.java#L11 (need to uncomment that line).

That repo itself is a POC minimized code. I was trying to use a kt_jvm_library just so it can be added as a dep to Main: https://github.com/vgrec/bazel-graphql-poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/BUILD#L17

Comment: looks like the orig repo owner also has been trying to find the solution here: https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/KJwMzFvNwDY

Comment: the generated files are present in: bazel-bin/src/main/java/com/example/apollo

Comment: sorry to spam but thanks a lot for your help. i have been stuck on this since a couple of days now :(